# need helcreate a program that finds the longest series of letters where the proceeding letter is larger than the last. Its outputting beg not beggh

Tags: python-3.x

###need helcreate a program that finds the longest series of letters where the proceeding letter is larger than the last. Its outputting beg not beggh

###Can you please help me determine why im getting beg and not beggh

```
s = 'azcbobobegghakl'

bigString = s[0]
longW = s[0]

for i in range(len(s)-1):   
    if s[i+1] >= s[i]:    
        bigString += s[i+1]
        if len(longW) < len(bigString):
            longW = bigString
            bigString = s[0]
            
    else:
        bigString = s[i+1]
        
        
        
print(longW)
```

Comment: Because you stop appending to `bigString` as soon as it is longer than `longW`. Remove the `bigString = s[0]` line.

Comment: Oh thanks, why does that only make it stop working after 3 letters? not 1 or 4?

Comment: Because the previous longest one (`az`) was 2 letters long.

Comment: Thanks mate. Any advice on the best way to learn coding? Iv done an MIT EDX course three times but I seem to forget things quickly and find it hard to progress. Whats the best way to learn?